# How do I make my picturebox detect collision and bounce off?

Tags: vb.net

this is my collision method but its just bouncing in the opposite direction.

```
'Collision Method 1
    Dim Col As Boolean = Collision(pxbox, pbpaddle1)
    If Col = True Then
        moveRight = Not moveRight
        moveDown = Not moveDown
    End If

    Dim Col2 As Boolean = Collision(pxbox, pbpaddle2)

    If Col2 = True Then
        moveRight = Not moveRight
        moveDown = Not moveDown
    End If
```

This is my function for the collision

```
Private Function Collision(ByVal P1 As PictureBox, ByVal P2 As PictureBox) As Boolean
    If P1.Left + P1.Width < P2.Left Then Return False
    If P2.Left + P2.Width < P1.Left Then Return False
    If P1.Top + P1.Height < P2.Top Then Return False
    If P2.Top + P2.Height < P1.Top Then Return False

    Return True

End Function
```

Comment: Try thinking this through.  If `P1.Left + P1.Width < P2.Left` then you are return false, which means you are not even checking the Y coordinates anymore.

Comment: I thought its checking that here If P1.Top + P1.Height < P2.Top Then Return False

Comment: `If P1.Bounds.IntersectsWith(P2.Bounds) Then BANG!`

Comment: When you hit `Return False`, it does not read the lines that follow. It exits the function from there.

Comment: But if you think about it, its only going to hit one side at a time.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems.

1. It's not clear whether P1, P2, or both are moving. Is a picturebox moving inside a containing picturebox, or are two pictureboxes moving on the screen?
2. In the function Collision, you should test all four possibilities and return false when none of the four is satisfied. Otherwise, there is a collision.
3. In your collision methods, for a collision with a vertical or horizontal "wall", you should change only Moveright or Movedown, but not both (unless the collision is in a corner).
4. If the collision is between two balls, you should use the average angle (weighted with speed and mass for each ball), and use the perpendicular of that angle as the "wall" the balls bounce off of. (This assumes the balls have no diameter.)